# Browserify + firebase + angularfire -- where to place var Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, browserify

First time using browserify in an Angular App. For a specific module, I am declaring my dependencies like so:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = require('angular')
    .module('bookbottles.showcase.dashboard', [
        require('angular-ui-router'),
        require('angularfire'),
        require('firebase')
    ])
    .config(require('./route'))
    .controller('DashboardCtrl', require('./controllers/DashboardCtrl'))
    .factory('DataStore', require('./services/DataStore'))
    .name;
```

However, I know that somewhere I need to write:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
```

Where can this be added? I need to reference Firebase in a service.

Answer (score 2):

I just added it directly above:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');

module.exports = require('angular')
    .module('bookbottles.showcase.dashboard', [
        require('angular-ui-router'),
        require('angularfire')
    ])
    .config(require('./route'))
    .controller('DashboardCtrl', require('./controllers/DashboardCtrl'))
    .factory('DataStore', require('./services/DataStore'))
    .name;
```

Now it's available to the service.